# Removing the H1 in a Custom Post Type also removes nav items

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Trying to remove the title in my custom post type "reviews", but when I apply the filter below, it not only removes the title but also the li items in my main nav menu. How can I target just the title?

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'remove_single_custom_post_titles', 10, 2 );
function remove_single_custom_post_titles( $title ) {
if( is_singular( 'portfolio' ) ):
return '';
else:
return $title;
endif;
}
```

Comment: In your theme, can you just not use `the_title()` for that CPT?

Comment: How could I try that? Sorry, i'm a bit of a noob.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right way but you need to change your function a little bit; try with this one:

```
function remove_single_custom_post_titles( $title ) { 
  if ( is_singular( 'portfolio' ) ) { 
    return false; 
  } 
return $title; }
```

I have not tested the snippet bit I think It might works. Let me know. Hope I helped you.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but nothing was removed though.

Comment: Can I see the code of your post type and the theme that you are using? Thanks

Comment: Diddy O, this is the CPT I am talking about https://www.hoosierstatebets.com/reviews/betmgm-sportsbook/

Comment: I see your link, I've noticed that you are using a child theme, so I think in your custom post type template you can remove the `the_title()` function, like @Chris Haas suggestion...but for real help I need to see the code, at now I'm very limitated...

Comment: Thanks for trying, but unable to figure it out, unfortunately.